# How do i dynamically show an image tag in blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a page that has a sortable table.

In the table header column I have:

```
<div>Inv. # @SortGlyph("inventory_number")</div>
```

and in the code block i have

```
    public string SortGlyph(string field)
    {
        if (field == _orderBy)
        {
            return _direction == "asc" ? "<img src='/images/uparrow.gif'>" : "<img src='/images/downarrow.gif'>";
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I think i need to use a RenderFragment to accomplish this, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to start with it.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple @if statement and a <img> tag ?

Comment: Because I want to reuse it, and having 5 nearly identical if statements per page makes my skin crawl

Comment: Why don't you create a component ?

Comment: Created a component, per your suggestion. You're right it's more reusable this way. Going to leave the question live because I'm really curious how to render an image.

Answer (score 1):

#### Direct answer:

This is the Blazor way:

```html
<div>Inv. # 
     @if IsSortedUpBy("inventory_number") {
        <img src='/images/uparrow.gif'>
     } 
     else if IsSortedDownBy("inventory_number") {
        <img src='/images/downarrow.gif'>
     }
</div>
```

Code:

```cs
public bool IsSortedUpBy(string field) => field == _orderBy && _direction == "asc";
public bool IsSortedDownBy(string field) => field == _orderBy && _direction != "asc";
```

#### Bonus Track:

Remember you can encapsulate behavior in your [own Blazor component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with parms:

```html
    <arrowdiv 
        label="Inv. # "
        state="@GetArrowStateForField(inventory_number)">
    </arrowdiv>
```

Comment: Yeah, I made it a component already per augu from mars' suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I left out the Field from this example because I wasn't sure how the rest of the component was implemented. I also considered you may need to sort by more than one field at a time. So to keep the answer simple I narrowed in on the actual question "How do i dynamically show an image tag in blazor?".

To dynamically show anything, simply wrap it in an `if` statement. To toggle the image you can actually just swap part of the string instead of replacing the entire `<img` element.

In the following example, if SortDirection is not set it will be not be shown due to the if statement. Otherwise, the image is shown and displays the proper image based on the ternary operator feeding the Direction property.

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortDirection))
{
    <img src='/images/@(Direction).gif'>
}

@code {
    string Direction => SortDirection == "asc" ? "uparrow" : "downarrow";
    [Parameter] public string SortDirection { get; set; }
}
```